# SOLVED Cannot get CORS to work no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**SOLVED** thanks to Freakish in the comments the issue was my endpoint was using `localhost:3030` instead of `http://localhost:3030`

Node is running on port 3030 and ionic is running in serve on port 8100 so `localhost:3030` and `localhost:8100` I know this is the problem and have looked for all the ways to implement and allow CORS.

I have tried everything under the sun from installing and using cors middleware to following other guides on implementing CORS. In the code below is where I tried following a guide to make a custom middleware and even that doesn't work.

Side note socket.io is working just fine.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '5mb' }));

// enable CORS
app.use(function( req, res, next ) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000000000");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) { res.send(200); } else { next(); } 
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socketIo.process(socket, io);
});

app.post('*', (req, res) => { 
    post.process(req, res);
});

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port: ' + port);
});
```

Besic error I get when trying to post.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3030/api/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: What is this: `http.listen`? Shouldn't it be `app.listen`

Comment: not sure if there is a difference I have done it both ways without a problem. before I posted this it was `app.listen` but i tried `http.listen` to try and get cors to work

Comment: Your request seems to be to `localhost:3030`, but the error message indicates it requires `http` - Have you tried `http://localhost:3030/`?

Comment: Isn't the error is self-explanatory? You are using `localhost:3030/...`, you should be using `http://localhost:3030/...` (or https). This particular error is caused by the client side.

Comment: wow @freakish you are totally correct that was exactly the issue and adding `http://` to the front of my endpoint fixed all issues with sending post to my server. Not sure how I missed that

Comment: Just a heads up: my server is hosted on Deno Deploy, and I was getting a CORS error because my endpoint was throwing a different error on the serverside. So if you're getting a CORS error even if you think you have cors properly set up on the backend, make sure that there are no other unrelated errors causing the CORS error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with `express` and a `reactJs` application. To solve it, I added the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library.

Example with cors on express:

```
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
    exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], // you can change the headers
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false
  });
);
```

Comment: appreciate the help so much!

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Instead of changing the title to SOLVED, you can mark the answer as correct and help other developers who are facing the same issue.

Comment: I would but nobody answered what the solution was. I did have your answer marked as the solution for a second but realized it wasn't the full solution and it required (unfortunately) a much more simpler solution hence me putting it in the question. if you would like to edit your answer to also include said solution I would be more than happy to mark your answer as such.

Comment: ok, now I saw the comments. To be fair I've never used `http` with `localhost` because it's useless since the browser removes the `http` from the URL

Comment: your not wrong I think that's why I missed that detail for so long.

Answer (score 5):

Chrome doesn't support localhost under Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * doesn't match localhost
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Try, **127.0.0.1** instead of localhost